What exactly is the cornerstone that Mark 12:10 speaks of?
We read in Mark 12:10(NKJV):

Have you not even read this Scripture:‘The stone which the builders rejected
has become the chief cornerstone.

(KJV uses the term 'head of the corner'  in place of 'chief corner stone')
There are varying definitions of the term 'corner stone'. According to one,  cornerstone (or foundation stone or setting stone) is the first stone set in the construction of a masonry foundation. All other stones will be set in reference to this stone, thus determining the position of the entire structure. Another definition says that cornerstones occupy the corner  position of the base ,between two walls of the structure, implying that there will be a minimum of four corner stones in an average house. Yet another view says that corner stone occupies the centre of the arch constituting the entry/ exit  points ( doors)' giving stability to the arch and to the entire building( See 'voussoir'  on Wikipedia).
The third definition seems to go with the narrative of 'stone that the builders rejected' in that once the foundation is  completed, doors are erected, and a  stone chiseled to perfection  is placed exactly at the centre of the arch in such a manner that it is easily visible to all those who enter the house.  The position of the stone is key to the strength of the arch .   This definition also goes well with Lk 20:18:   " Whosoever shall fall upon that stone shall be broken; but on whomsoever it shall fall, it will grind him to powder."
As per  the first  definition,corner stone is the very starting point of construction, and there is little chance of a rejected stone becoming the corner stone once the construction has commenced.
Going by the second definition, there are more than one corner stones, and the likelihood of the  Chief Corner-stone being there,is bleak .
My question, therefore , is: What exactly is the 'cornerstone' that Mark 12:10 speaks of, in so far as it relates to architecture ?

I found twelve texts relevant : Job 38:6 ; Psalm 118:22 ; Isaiah 28:16 ; Jeremiah 51:26 ; Zechariah 10:4 ; Matthew 21:42 ; Mark 12:20 ; Luke 20:17 ; Acts 4:11 ; Ephesians 2:20 ;
1 Peter 2:6 ; 1 Peter 2:7 Up-voted +1.

Strange that seven answers have been provided but only two upvotes to the question . . . . ..

That in deed is the paradox, Nigel J. My question of the dress code of Jewish widows on CSE received no answers but three upvotes !

There are twelve relevant texts in regard to the ‘head of the corner’.
Firstly : Job 38:6 ; Psalm 118:22 ; Isaiah 28:16 ; Jeremiah 51: 6
Job, the Psalmist, Isaiah and Jeremiah all refer to the Hebrew word pinnah which is angle/chief/pinnacle in concept. There is no suggestion of that which is laid on the ground.
Isaiah, it is true, refers to yasad - establish or found - but also uses the word pinnah emphasising that the establishment is founded by means of a raised pinnah.
Then : Matthew 21:42 ; Mark 12:10 ; Luke 20:17 ; Acts 4:11 ; Ephesians 2:20 ; 1 Peter 2:6 ; 1 Peter 2:7.
The first four refer to ‘head of corner’ (kephalis gonia). Peter then also refers to acrongonia (top of corner). Paul follows Peter and also refers to top of corner.

In sum, all references in scripture indicate the ascended Christ as the head or top of the corner. Thus, from a raised position every part of the building is sighted and made true to that exalted stone. Whether length or breadth or height, the sighting is taken from that single stone.
Its dimensions determine the dimensions and the placing of the rest of the building.
Paul’s mention of being a master-builder and laying a foundation are supplementary to the above concept. He chooses where to lay the foundation (I suggest firmly in the Hebrew scriptures) and he builds upon that foundation and that foundation only.
Jesus Christ and him crucified, as set forth in figure and type and shadow in the Hebrew scripture and as enlarged upon in the reality of his earthly ministry, his sufferings, his death and his resurrection : this is the foundation which Paul lays.
Nevertheless it is only in accord with Christ as risen and ascended that the building of the Church arises, true to Him who reigns over all, the Head and the Top of the corner, seated in the throne of his Father, and Head over all things to the Church, his Body and the House of God.

On response to comment, the stone unused by some (they preferring to build a house for God and a dwelling for God's people without that stone) then becomes 'superfluous' on the building site and many stumble on it.
They have no use for it, thus it is a 'rock of offence'. They don't need it, it gets in the way, and they abhor it.
Thus for those who build and do not give precedence to the head of the corner ; or, pretending to do so, they use other material and give away the fact that their bulding is out of true, not fit for purpose and even faulty and ready to collapse.
As for sunthlao it is only used twice in scripture (thlao itself, never) and both in this context, Matthew and Luke, therefore it must be by interpretation that we explain its use.
I have always assumed, and still have no further comment to make, that in falling upon that stone, one will be 'broken' (that is to say, rendered incapable of personal effort, thus dependent) but if it falls upon one, an aggressive act designed to be catastrophic, then one will be rendered permanently incapable of all function.

Thanks, Nigel J, for taking my question in the right perspective and for  giving definitive inputs .Only Lk 20:18 remains to be clarified now: Can the same stone act as something ON which someone may fall, and also as something which FALLS ON someone .

@KadalikattJosephSibichan Thank you ; and done, as requested.

Thanks, Nigel J. That was so kind of you.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan Glad to be of service.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan  Is your writing (mentioned in your profile) in English ? I notice that you are in Karala. That is where Siju George lived, who contributed here until he passed away with Covid in about 2021. His brother lives here in the UK and I went to the London area to meet him.

Thanks, Nigel J for the personal outreach. I do belong to Kerala, but have been staying in Delhi since 1989 doing Union Govt service. I mostly write in  English ( which has , of course, been influenced by Indian languages  )

Nigel J, I hope we can be in touch . My email id is: kjsibichan@hotmail.com  .WhatsApp: +91-11-9871385117. I follow Indian Standard Time.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan   Got that. Thank you. Will be in touch soon.

The main question, repeated at the very end is, "What exactly is the cornerstone that Mark 12:10 speaks of?"
Inbetween are three points about locations of three different types of cornerstones. This is where position of such stones is detailed. The first is placed as the very first stone to be set in the construction of a masonry foundation. The second matter of position has four cornerstones, at the corners of (most likely) a square or oblong building. The third type of stone is the apex of a curved dome, crowning the stones at each side of a door.
The text in question only has one direct clue as to what Jesus was referring to. He quoted from a Hebrew scripture his listeners knew full well - Psalm 118:22-23. And who were his listeners? Mark 11:27 identifies them as the chief priests, scribes and elders in Jerusalem. Because of their intransigence, Jesus then addressed a series of parables to them and they knew he was identifying them as vineyard servants who killed the owner's only son. At the end of that parable, Jesus asked, "Have you not read this scripture?" and quoted Psalm 118:22-23. Yet that Psalm does not tell us its meaning! However, context in Mark chapter 12 clearly points to Christ.
This is where it needs to be stressed that this "chief cornerstone" is not a what, but a who. The question must become, "WHO is this one, who is rejected by 'builders' but who then becomes the chief cornerstone?" It is the risen Christ.
The preceding parable is clear. Those intransigent men were but servants. Jesus was the Son. And his was the inheritance they sought to snatch to themselves by killing the Son. The parable shows that the Lord of that vineyard will "destroy the husbandmen, and will give the vineyard unto others" - Mark 12:9
How God would do that is the key point in Psalm 118:22-23 and Mark 12-10. "The stone which the builders rejected is become the head of the corner." It is Christ, risen from the dead, who has become chief corner stone in the house of God not made with hands, that is, the ecclesia of the living God.
Once more, the meaning has nothing to do with a literal building made with literal stones, for it is all about the risen Christ, who builds his ecclesia (Church). The Apostolic foundation was laid, Christ being its chief cornerstone, which alone can bear the weight of the Church, for time and eternity. Paul said "I have laid the foundation" in 1 Corinthians 3:10, and no man can lay any other:

"[You are] fellow citizens with the saints, and of the household of
God, and are built upon the foundation of the apostles and prophets,
Jesus Christ himself being the chief cornerstone, in whom all the
building fitly framed together groweth into an holy temple in the
Lord: In whom ye also are builded together for an habitation of God
through the Spirit." Ephesians 2:19-22 K.J.V [emphasis mine].

Here is a quotation from a booklet going into all of that:

"The Church, that is alone worthy the name, and heir to the benefits, is built upon the apostolic foundation. However, this building is spiritual, and also so is the foundation upon which it rests... The building of foundations commences out of sight beneath the surface of the earth, up from the rock which has been bared, to level with the surface of the ground. Only such sound, stable and deep foundations are able to take the weight of the successive stories to rise thereupon...


This is in the spiritual sense precisely the function of the apostolic foundation. Nothing but this foundation... can take the weight of the church of God both for time and eternity; and nothing else bear the stress when the rain of fiery judgment descends, and the floods of vindictive wrath come, and the winds of furious vengeance blow, and beat thereon...


The apostles have bared the rock from all that is of the earth, and within a carefully defined area have dug down and built up the solid foundation of apostolic doctrine. In their writings there is nothing of the flesh or of the world or that is earthly; all has been excavated. There remains solely what is of God. But not haphazardly so... not upon what is merely traditional, ecclesiastical, historical, national or geographical - all that must be excavated too (Eph. 2:20)...


...Since at the beginning of the Church these foundations of doctrine were laid, and since at the end of the age in eternity nothing remains in glory but what is above and upon these foundations, I say to my soul, and to him that feareth God, Take heed how ye are built thereon!" Foundations Uncovered, pp 35-37, John Metcalfe, 1983 http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

Summary: This chief cornerstone is not a what, but a who - the risen Christ, and it is a spiritual building that the gates of Hades will never overcome that he is building, therefore there is no question of any location - it is all spiritual, heavenly, symbolic language. Yet Christians who are truly built upon the Apostolic foundation, are secure for eternity, as Jesus is their chief cornerstone.

+1 As it is, this build up as Jesus being the chief Cornerstone is all inclusive and you've shown a clear answer of our faith based upon Jesus. Which brings up another related question - if modern apostles and prophets are not absolutely built upon the Jesus Christ of the scriptures (his teachings included, as explained by Paul in 1 Timothy 6:3-5 and John in 2 John 1:9-11), who are they?

Thanks, Anne, for the scholarly inputs. What I wanted was a down- to-earth picturisation of the stone Jesus would have his audience visualising. Your answer suggests that a cornerstone could occupy different positions in the building . Maybe that is why Jesus says in Lk 20:18: "Whosoever shall fall upon that stone shall be broken; but on whomsoever it shall fall, it will grind him to powder."

It is a huge subject, and requires a lot of effort to understand.
Nothing is accidental in the use of Greek words for the Bible by the apostles and evangelists of Christianity.
The text says "angle head", not "cornerstone". The concept has nothing to do just with a cornerstone (i.e. only the edge and the stone); The phrase is: "The head (edge) of the angle", therefore, the angle is included in the text, whereas if we say just "cornerstone" (i.e. the edge stone), then, the angle (the two sides) is not included, and that is which includes all the meaning. This is a highly allegorical concept, and the stone is understood as a point on a building that acts as in an angle, the head (edge) of the angle.
The translation is this
The stone which the builders disapproved, this was appointed as the head of the angle: this, it was done by the Lord, and is marvelous in our eyes!
I think we have to travel way back in time to understand these words and the meaning of their connection in the sentence. And I will try to do so.
I may get a bit tedious in referring to various things, but it is important to understand words that have a deeper meaning.
It is important to understand the root of the word "γωνία" (ghonía), and the ancient symbolic Semitic letters, because the Greeks, it is said, got the alphabet from the Phoenicians. This means that most languages that exist today, if not all, are branches of a common language.
The word "γωνία" (noun [English angle, Latin anguli]), comes from the also noun "γόνυ" (the angle formed by the foot; the knee, the angular part of the foot). It has "ω" and not "o" because it forms a large angle (Ω mega), and the word is in the feminine gender, because, as we define the words of the feminine gender in Greek with the definite article "H", in ancient times something big and special was meant; taken from the Semitic letter (Hebrew ח [het], the English letter “H” as a consonant of exhalation, which represented in pictographs a great dividing wall indicating that which is beyond it, as something impossible to reach, and sublime; i.e. beyond the limits of man).
The word "γόνυ" (Lat. genu, Eng. knee, N. Gr. γόνατο), essentially, also functions, as a connection, connecting the base of a man's or animal's leg, with the rest of his upper body; but also as a base, when we fall to our knees (or bend our knees) to beg someone, to not harm us, which indicates an act of safety ("αγκωνάρι" [agonáre] = massive cornerstone which used for buildings, from ἀγκών [agón] = elbow) or to pray to God. A Greek word is "γονυπετέω" (ghonepetéo) < "πίπτω γόνυ" (pépto ghóne [to fall on my knees]), "κλίνω γόνυ" (kléno ghóni [to bend my knees]).
The first meaning, which functions as a connection, must have deep roots in antiquity, and this is, I believe, in essence, the meaning identified by the biblical phrase "κεφαλὴν γωνίας" (kefalén ghonéas). I don't think it has to do with the “αγκωνάρι” (agonári) of a building, which supports the building from a corner, as we would interpret it as: the basic or head corner support of the building, and be that Christ. e.g. Christ set Peter up as a rock, though not in the sense of an αγκωνάρι (agonári), but as the base, which functions as the initial structure. Therefore, it cannot be understood that Peter is the basis and Christ is one of the three or four agonári of the structure (of the Church). Here, of course, the Lord's rich gift to Peter is also implied (a rock, as a base), and its rich meaning, which gives Peter immense honor, will be fully understood below.
The word "γόνυ," has a root of two consonants and a semi-consonant "γνυ"; the "o" marks, perhaps, the small shape, referring to the foot (probably "Y" [with the sound "w"] was originally "F" [same sound propably], which, both of which, have the sense of a pillar, which fastens a building. The "Y", has the image of an ancient cup [ancient glass] which is in the shape of a "Y", and it holds water, or wine). The letter "Γ" (with sound "gh", the 3rd letter of the alphabet) is a foot, which also is an ancient iconography of the letter, while the letter "N" (with sound "n"), according to the information we have from ancient pictographs, symbolizes an infant. An infant, as we know, walks on its knees. The "γνυ", i.e., here denotes, perhaps, the part of the foot by which the infant walks and supports its body, or the walking by which the infant supports itself (knees). The connection (united) is shown to be one with the ground. So, in general, "γνυ" (knee) has the meaning of the property which joins a base (ground) to the rest of the body (infant).
In this case, we have three meanings.
Introduction to the name of Peter
Πέτρος (Pétros > Peter), taken from the Hebrew word "כֵּיפָא" (kephá) which has the meaning of "holding the passage (which comes under the base)". On the other hand, one sense of the word "πέτρα" means a massive stone; But the Hebrew or Aramaic name, since it originated there, should be considered in the ancient letters to determine the meaning. It is certain that the letter Π (with the sound "p"), both in Hebrew and Greek, marks a gate, a passage. The vowel (the next letter) does not reveal a relevant meaning to me, so it is probably an auxiliary pronunciation vowel. The next letter is T; this letter does not mean a closure or hold, but it does mean its derivative, which comes from the same ancient Phoenician, X; the X in front of the Π closes the entrance. Generally X and T are two rods, two bars. So Matthew chosed to use the T, because he is Aramean and he formed in his mind the equivalent letter of the ת (taw); I don't know if he had in his mind the X with the same meaning. However, the next letter Ρ (sound "rh"), I am not sure what it means here; this letter generally marks a flow, as well as a mindset or spirit of a person. If it has to do with the meaning of the Greek word "ῥύω" (rhéo) beginning with "Ρ", and meaning "to turn away, to free”, i.e. from bad circumstances, where the original meaning is perhaps, from what I can see, "to support the spirit, to judge righteously", then perhaps, the word Πέτρος (ΠΤΡ [the “o” and “ς” indicates masculine gender]), may mean "the support of Christ by the closing of the passage". Is of course a conjecture, but it is still a logical conclusion.
(cf. Epistle to the Ephesians 2,20-22)

Here we have an elbow (L bow with right-angle); where the base is Peter, taken from the Hebrew word "כֵּיפָא" (kephá) which has the meaning of "holding the passage (which comes under the base)", i.e., what Jesus said in Matthew: “κἀγὼ δέ σοι λέγω ὅτι σὺ εἶ Πέτρος, καὶ ἐπὶ ταύτῃ τῇ πέτρᾳ οἰκοδομήσω μου τὴν ἐκκλησίαν καὶ πύλαι ᾅδου οὐ κατισχύσουσιν αὐτῆς” (Matthew 16,18). Which means: "And I say to you that you are Pétros, and upon this Pétra I will build my Church, and the gates of hell shall not prevail against her." The head (edge) of the angle is Christ who holds his body, and together with the twelve apostles and Paul, they lay the foundation and upon them the Church is built, who are all Christians in general, including Jesus Christ and the apostles, including Peter, i.e. the body of Christ, the elbow (L).

(cf. Epistle to the Ephesians 2,11-19)

a) The other explanation, is the elbow (L bow, which means right-angle) in the sense of a connection again, where it joins the two parts of the arm; where arm, according the ancient iconography, means the power of man, etc; by extension, the power of the Son of man (of Jesus Christ), where his power is his people, and whom he constitutes. The base of the L is the old Israel. The difference is that the old Israel fought to occupy territory on earth, lived for the interests of his flesh, and looked with his face to the earth, so the base of L is the old Israel; while the new Israel fights to occupy territory spiritually, lives for the interests of others, and looks with their face to heaven, so the upright part of L is the new Israel (Christians). On the other hand, the Law was set as a basis, as a principle. The basis of the Moses. Also, Abraham, Isaac and Jacob (> Israel) are the three patriarchs, and from Judah David the king came, and from him Jesus Christ came, the head (edge) of the angle, now he came. And from there onwards there is an ascent, because the base is finished and the head of the angle has come and taken its place. Where together with the 12 apostles and Paul, they lay a foundation and the Christians are built on it and the Church takes shape, the shape of an angle. And now these two lines are united. b) Here the ideal letter of the alphabet which represents this angle with the two sides joined is the "A" (álpha). The pronunciation also of this is the separation, between those at inside (old Israel) and those at outside (Gentiles), driving out the separation with the blowing of the mouth. And what is awe-inspiring is the verb Paul uses "λύω" (léo [λύσας past tense participle nominative 3rd singular] Epistle to the Ephesians 2,14b), which perfectly expresses the meaning of his pronunciation. New Greek equivalent "διαλύω", English word "scatter". While the Hebrew equivalent letter is א (áleph). which is divided into two strands with a partition, separating the inside from the outside. Even the alphabet, while meaning other things in the beginning, concealed another meaning. Everything is destined by God!

(cf, Epistle to the Ephesians 2,14-16; All the Epistle to the Hebrews)

a) Another elbow (L bow), even stronger view, is that the angle here means the change of course that forms an angle. That is, the turning from one line to another line of a different course. And the head of this angle, that is, the cause, is Jesus Christ, who was incarnated, crucified and resurrected to mediate between God and man and to abolish the sin that resulted from the transgression of the Law and to give a new way of forgiveness. And he made an angle of 180 degrees; and no longer does the people expect to be forgiven by the blood of the slaughter of animals, just as there is no holy of holies on earth, but in heaven; and so the people enter the holy of holies in heaven, directly to the Father through Jesus Christ, receiving forgiveness of sins by the blood of the now heavenly Lamb. It became a 180 degree angle. where Christ now acts as a priest, offering his own blood, not like the priests of the earth, where every time the high priest died, another high priest had to be appointed, whereas Jesus is the high priest, and the real priest, for eternity. (cf. see Epistle to the Hebrews). b) Again, here we have the so-called L bow, where the basis is the Law of Moses through the eyes of Jesus Christ, "Think not that I came to abolish the law or the prophets; I did not come to abolish but to fulfill", where he gave us his teaching, and then he ascended and sent the Spirit of help, exhortation, guidance in the truth, etc. And then he ascended and intercedes between man and the Father, sending the Holy Spirit. And this L bow unites those who come to God through Jesus Christ who sends the Holy Spirit and acts as the head of the angle, and unites man to God, the so-called engagement of the Spirit.


+1 Great answer! Well researched with solid support.

@Dieter read again the last paragraph cause i changed it.

Yes. My reservation is that analogies are powerful tools to convey complex concepts without resorting to a flood of mind-numbing technical jargon, however, analogies have limits. One can argue that the essence of our entire existence is part of an enormous allegory, but my objection is that this perspective leads to unintended conclusions when taken too far, including mysticism and the sod in PRDS. Thus, shallow applications are the strongest, while the deepest applications are of necessity the weakest.

Your answer has been automatically flagged for being edited over 20 times. While editing is a good thing in general, excessive edits is disruptive for others on the site. Please try to make your edits in batches, rather than making multiple small edits in a short period of time.

@curiousdannii Yes, I understand that it's not correct, I was just off topic on various issues, but I also wanted to fill in some others. In general, I did change it many times, but this was mainly because I wanted to deliver a complete explanation.

What
According to Strong, the Hebrew word pinnah - פִּנָּה can mean "bulwark, chief, corner, stay, or tower." Most translators speak of a cornerstone or foundation stone, but some refer to a capstone. The idea of a pinnacle or bullark actually makes a bit more sense in the context, at least to me.
Who
Turning to the identity of the "cornerstone," the answer depends on whether one accepts the Talmud's interpretation or the New Testament's. For the Talmud it is King David. For the NT it is Jesus. The quote is from psalm 72:

21 I thank you that you have answered me
and have become my salvation. 22 The stone that the builders rejected
has become the cornerstone. 23 This is the Lord's doing;
it is marvelous in our eyes. 24 This is the day that the Lord has made;
let us rejoice and be glad in it.

Jewish view
According to the Talmud, these verses were recited by key members of the young David's family and the prophet Samuel, when the future king was still a boy. Pesachim 119a:13:

David recited: “I will give thanks to You, for You have answered me”
(vs. 21), with regard to the success of his reign. Jesse
(David's father) recited: “The stone which the builders rejected has
become the chief keystone” (vs. 22). The brothers of David
recited: “This is the Lord’s doing; it is marvelous in our eyes”
(vs. 23). Samuel the Prophet recited: “This is the day which
the Lord has made; we will rejoice and be glad in it” (vs. 24).

David was the youngest son of Jesse. He  was out tending the sheep and had been excluded at first when Jesse presented his sons to the prophet Samuel. (1 Samuel 16) So in the Talmud, he is considered to be the cornerstone who had been been rejected.
Christian view
In the NT, however, it is Jesus, rather than David, who is the cornerstone. In all three synoptic gospels, the "stone that the builders rejected" quote follows the Parable of the Vineyard Workers. It refers to the landlord's son and thus, by implication, to Jesus. This is made explicit in Act 4, where Peter declares:

Jesus Christ the Nazorean whom you crucified,
whom God raised from the dead... 11 is the stone rejected by you, the builders, which has
become the cornerstone.

Conclusion: Thus, from a Christian perspective the cornerstone is clearly Jesus. For Jews, however, it was King David. In terms of architecture, the word translated as "cornerstone" could mean either a foundation stone or the pinnacle.

Mark 12:10 refers to the "stone the builders rejected" becoming the "cornerstone" (or "head of the corner"), a quotation from Psalm 118:22. In biblical interpretation, this cornerstone metaphor has rich theological and symbolic layers, connecting to both the Hebrew Bible and later Jewish and Christian traditions. To understand its meaning, we can draw insights from The Testament of Solomon.
The Testament of Solomon A 22:7

And Jerusalem was being built and the sanctuary was nearing completion. And there was a great cornerstone that I wished to place at the head of the corner for the fulfillment of the sanctuary of God.

The Testament of Solomon A 22:7

καὶ ἦν Ἰερουσαλήμ ᾠκοδομωμένη καὶ ὁ ναὸς συνεπληροῦντο. καὶ ἦν λίθος ἀκρογωνιαῖος μέγας ὃν ἐβουλόμην θεῖναι εἰς κεφαλὴν γωνίας τῆς πληρώσεως τοῦ ναοῦ τοῦ θεοῦ.

The Testament of Solomon A 23:4

I Solomon, being uplifted, said: "Truly now the scripture, which says, 'The stone that the builders rejected, this one has become the head of the corner,'" and the rest.

The Testament of Solomon A 23:4

ἐγὼ δὲ Σολομῶν ἐπαιρόμενος εἶπον• Ἀληθῶς νῦν ἐπληρώθη ἡ γραφὴ ἡ λέγουσα• Λίθον ὃν ἀπεδοκίμασαν οἱ οἰκοδομοῦντες οὗτος ἐγενήθη μὲν εἰς κεφαλὴν γωνίας, καὶ τὰ λοιπά.

Context in The Testament of Solomon

The Cornerstone and the Temple:

In Testament of Solomon A 22:7, Solomon speaks of a large cornerstone intended to complete the sanctuary of God. Here, the cornerstone is the finishing element of the temple, symbolizing completion, unity, and divine presence. The imagery ties the cornerstone to God's dwelling and the perfection of divine purposes.


Rejection and Fulfillment:

In Testament of Solomon A 23:4, Solomon reflects on the fulfillment of Scripture, explicitly identifying the rejected stone as the head cornerstone. This verse indicates that what is dismissed as unworthy or insignificant by human standards gains ultimate significance in God's plan.



Mark 12:10 in Light of This
In the context of Mark 12, Jesus uses the parable of the tenants to critique the religious leaders who reject God’s messengers, including the "beloved son." By quoting Psalm 118:22, Jesus applies the cornerstone imagery to himself, suggesting that he is the essential element in God's redemptive plan, rejected by the builders (religious authorities) but chosen by God for ultimate glorification.
Key Insights

Symbol of Christ:

The cornerstone represents Christ as the foundation of the new spiritual "temple" (cf. Ephesians 2:20), fulfilling the sanctuary symbolism of Testament of Solomon A 22:7. His rejection by human authorities parallels the rejection mentioned in the Testament.


Divine Reversal:

Just as the rejected stone is elevated to the head of the corner, so too is Jesus, through his resurrection and exaltation, placed as the pivotal figure in God's kingdom.


Temple Theology:

Both The Testament of Solomon and Mark 12 draw on temple imagery. The cornerstone's role in completing the temple emphasizes Jesus as the fulfillment of the covenant, uniting God's people into a new spiritual dwelling.



The cornerstone in Mark 12:10, interpreted alongside The Testament of Solomon, embodies the paradox of rejection and divine selection. It illustrates that what humanity overlooks often holds the greatest value in God's purposes. In both texts, the cornerstone serves as a theological emblem of God's sovereignty, the unity of his people, and the completion of his salvific work.

+1 Interesting perspective using a surprising source--pseudographical, but historical nevertheless.

Jesus is the cornerstone or the stone cut without hands in which we who believe are built upon.
“let it be known to all of you and to all the people of Israel that by the name of Jesus Christ of Nazareth, whom you crucified, whom God raised from the dead—by him this man is standing before you well. This Jesus is the stone that was rejected by you, the builders, which has become the cornerstone.”
‭‭Acts‬ ‭4‬:‭10‬-‭11‬ ‭ESV‬‬
“As you come to him, a living stone rejected by men but in the sight of God chosen and precious, you yourselves like living stones are being built up as a spiritual house, to be a holy priesthood, to offer spiritual sacrifices acceptable to God through Jesus Christ. For it stands in Scripture: “Behold, I am laying in Zion a stone, a cornerstone chosen and precious, and whoever believes in him will not be put to shame.””
‭‭1 Peter‬ ‭2‬:‭4‬-‭6‬ ‭ESV‬‬


Eph 2:19- you are fellow citizens with the saints and members of the household of God, 20 built on the foundation of the apostles and prophets, Christ Jesus himself being the cornerstone, 21 in whom the whole structure, being joined together, grows into a holy temple in the Lord

Is Jesus a stone? The whole analogy is a metaphor for his centrality to all other foundations already laid. When they were laid is irrelevant as Jesus place in the foundation was already known.

1 Pet 1:20 having been foreknown indeed before the foundation of the world, but having been revealed in the last times for the sake of you

What exactly is the 'cornerstone' that Mark 12:10 speaks of?
Other verses answer this quite succinctly, Jesus IS the cornerstone and that is all we need to be mindful of. All other stones must align with the cornerstone. Obviously, this is a spiritual concept expressed through a building foundation metaphor. Whether there are other stones on other corners is moot. Jesus is the author of salvation, which is what the temple symbolises.

‭‭Acts‬ ‭4‬:‭10‬- This Jesus is the stone that was rejected by you, the builders, which has become the cornerstone.‭‬


In Mark 12:10, Jesus references Psalm 118:22:

The stone that the builders rejected
has become the cornerstone.

Christ is the cornerstone.

Ephesians 2:20: "built on the foundation of the apostles and
prophets, Christ Jesus himself being the cornerstone,"
1 Corinthians 3:11: "For no one can lay a foundation other than
that which is laid, which is Jesus Christ."


Jesus as the cornerstone is the essential foundation on which Christianity is built.


Matthew 21:42: "Jesus said to them, “Have you never read in the
Scriptures:
“‘The stone that the builders rejected
has become the cornerstone; this was the Lord's doing,
and it is marvelous in our eyes’?"
Acts 4:11: "This Jesus is the stone that was rejected by you, the
builders, which has become the cornerstone."


Jesus, who was rejected by the leaders (builders), becomes the key
element (cornerstone) of God's redemptive plan.

Therefore:

The cornerstone is the first and most important stone in a building's
foundation, so Jesus is the foundational element of the faith.
The cornerstone determines the position and aligns the
entire structure, so Jesus sets the direction and alignment for
believers.
The cornerstone is crucial for the integrity of a building, so Jesus is
essential for the integrity of the Church
Jesus, though rejected by many, was exalted to the most important position.


I don't rightly know the answer to your question and there are alot of interesting answers. I had always taken this to mean the outside bottom corner stone, as in modern construction, that would have the builders name and the date of construction, kind of a signature on the finished work of the building. Since the Pharisees loved shows of wealth, they probably valued cornerstones made of some valuable material, and the rejection of Christ here sort of resembles the fake and true grails in Indiana Jones And The Last Crusade. Because Christ in actuality was a lowly and humble, practical stone, that just looked like a normal stone, he was passed over by the Pharisees for not being shiny and expensive enough.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Frazer (2006: pp. 106–107) in The Golden Bough from 1890 charts the various propitiary sacrifices and effigy substitution such as the shadow, states that:
Nowhere, perhaps, does the equivalence of the shadow to the life or soul come out more clearly than in some customs practised to this day in South-eastern Europe. In modern Greece, when the foundation of a new building is being laid, it is the custom to kill a cock, a ram, or a lamb, and to let its blood flow on the foundation-stone, under which the animal is afterwards buried. The object of the sacrifice is to give strength and stability to the building. But sometimes, instead of killing an animal, the builder entices a man to the foundation-stone, secretly measures his body, or a part of it, or his shadow, and buries the measure under the foundation-stone; or he lays the foundation-stone upon the man's shadow. It is believed that the man will die within the year. The Roumanians of Transylvania think that he whose shadow is thus immured will die within forty days; so persons passing by a building which is in course of erection may hear a warning cry, Beware lest they take thy shadow! Not long ago there were still shadow-traders whose business it was to provide architects with the shadows necessary for securing their walls. In these cases the measure of the shadow is looked on as equivalent to the shadow itself, and to bury it is to bury the life or soul of the man, who, deprived of it, must die. Thus the custom is a substitute for the old practice of immuring a living person in the walls, or crushing him under the foundation-stone of a new building, in order to give strength and durability to the structure, or more definitely in order that the angry ghost may haunt the place and guard it against the intrusion of enemies.[3]

Welcome, Kenneth Faulke. Please try to integrate your answers into a single answer. I have heard it said that long ago human sacrifices would take place during construction of bridges, under the false belief that they would strengthen the structure. But, our focus is on the corner stone and the position it occupies in the building.

Thank you, I'm new to using this forum. I wonder if what you mention about bridges is the sources of the "Troll under the bridge" trope. Anyway, the allegorical picture I see in Frazers' observations are that Christ's death and burial=The inaugural sacrifice for the nascent Church as The New Temple and his resurrection and numinousity=The (w)holy angry ghost that haunts the grounds, protecting The  Church from interlopers, vendors, and others who would come in over the garden wall, instead of by The True Gate.

Kenneth Foulke, you will find on Google many folklores relating to spirits of those people sacrificed for strength of the bridge, staying over or under the bridge. Interestingly, troll could be a corrupt adaptation of toll that many authorities charge for crossing of the bridge.
